# Internationalizing a map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, maps, internationalization

I am working on a map of a city in Cambodia. Unfortunately, the characters and names of nearly all places are all displayed in Khmer, which, despite being able to speak, I am not able to read.

I remember encountering this distinct problem and solving it once already over a year ago (around June of 2021) but I can't remember what I did. In the solution I found back then, I could use QGIS just like Google Maps with everything in the base layer translated to English or a transliterated form of Khmer in Latin characters which is also fine for me.

What I have tried so far:

- Changing application language to EN
- Check the global variable in the project (the language is set to EN)

I noticed in the following OSM wiki that there are a few providers of internationalized maps https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_internationalization but I do not know how to use those as my base layer.

Answer (score 1):

To get additional basemaps in QGIS, including some with place names in english for Cambodia (e.g. Google Maps), [run this script by Klas Karlsson](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/klakar/QGIS_resources/master/collections/Geosupportsystem/python/qgis_basemaps.py) in the QGIS Python console: copy the code, then go to Menu Plugins > Python console > paste the code > press the green triangle icon to run the code. When you now expand the XYZ tiles entry in the Browser panel, you find a lot of additional basemaps.

Other options include:

- [QuickMapServices](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quick_map_services/) Plugin
- [MapTiler](https://www.maptiler.com/qgis-plugin/?utm_source=qgis&utm_medium=product&utm_campaign=qgis-plugin) Plugin